# What does the notation $O(x^n)$ mean?

Tags: polynomials, notation, irreducible-polynomials, rational-functions

I am reading a book about Padé Approximations, and I am trying to understand the following line:

We denote the $[L/M]$ Padé approximant to $A(x)$ by

$A(x) - P_L(x)/Q_M(x) = O(x^{L+M+1})$

where $P_L(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $L$ and $Q_M(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $M$. $A(x)$ is a formal power series $\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j$

What does the $O(x^{L+M+1})$ mean?

Thanks in advance

The book is *Essentials of Padé Approximants* by George A. Baker, JR.

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Ahh thank you! It helps to know what to search for, sometimes

Comment: In this specific case it means that the first $M+L+1$ terms in $A(x)Q_M(x)-P_L(x)$ vanish, i.e., the first term of this power series has degree $M+L+1$ or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Usually $f(x)=O(g(x))$ means that for all sufficiently large $x$ $f(x)\leq k \cdot g(x)$. That is, $\lim \sup_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for

Comment: Read more on asymptotic notation [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Asymptotic_Notation).

Comment: That was exactly what I was going to say!